# FileNotFoundException when using Windows Store Apps ApplicationData Current Settings

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I recently started getting an error when using the current application data settings in a Windows Store App

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer roamingSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings ;
if (roamingSettings.Values.ContainsKey("UserName"))
{
    username.Text = roamingSettings.Values["UserName"].ToString();
}
```

A System.IO.FileNotFoundException with additional information:

> 'Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current' threw an exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
>
> Additional information: The system cannot find the file specified.
> (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)

occurs on the first line.  Oddly, this only started happening recently, and the same code did work before.

Has anyone else experienced this and could help shine a light on what is going on?

Addition:  Also it seems to be machine specific.  This error doesn't occur on my laptop, only on my desktop.  Could it be a corrupted setting?

Comment: Is there a difference between the account you're logged in with both machines. Roaming Settings wouldn't work if you weren't logged in with a Microsoft account, but I wouldn't expect it to fail with an exception like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it was intermittent error.  A few shut down and reboots solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Goto the file Property ,(the file that planned to add in code).Set Build Action property to Content..

Then this problem will solves...